# Node.js equivalent of Play! Framework

Tags: model-view-controller, node.js, coffeescript

I've been looking into using Node.js + CoffeeScript for my project instead of the Play! framework. I like the idea of being able to write both my client-side and server-side code in CoffeeScript, which is a great language.

I've taken a quick look through the list of frameworks here https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules and there seem to be quite a few choices in the web framework market. Can anyone recommend one that has a strong MVC architecture, and would afford the smoothest transition to Node.js?

Some of my nice-to-have features:

- Built-in security functionality
- ORM/some other kind of MySQL querying API
- View templates

Comment: You may want to check nice list of MVC Node frameworks at: http://nodeframework.com/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express (Django-like web) + Mongoose (ORM)

http://expressjs.com
http://mongoosejs.com

EDIT: Sorry, forgot the part about MySQL. Mongoose is for MongoDB only. In that case, try Sequelize: http://sequelizejs.com

Comment: I've looked at Express and that appears to be quite nice, but mongoosejs is MongoDB centric whereas i'm looking for a good MySql orm solution.

Comment: @Jason Miesionczek Answer edited to fit your requirements. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

[compound.js](http://compoundjs.com/), formerly RailwayJS, (express-on-railway) adds rails-style structure and MVC to [Express](http://expressjs.com/)

Comment: RailwayJS seems like an option for those devs who like Rails. I am not one of them. Partly the reason why i specified Play! and not just any MVC framework in general. I appreciate your answer, but i'm not looking for a Rails clone.

Answer (score 0):

try [Batman.js](http://batmanjs.org/)

- extremely fast app server based on node.js uses all your same app code (models, controllers) so you don't duplicate code*
- include specific server side code, like security or proprietary code or extra validations*
- can do extra things like compile and minimize your code

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at the:

Meteor https://www.meteor.com/

koa.js http://koajs.com/

Sails.js http://sailsjs.org/

MEAN.io http://mean.io/#!/